# C++: Extract N highest elements from container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Quite frequently I need to extract the N (> 1) highest elements from an unsorted STL container. The naive way to do this is using `<queue>`.

Is there a quicker, less boilerplate way?

Comment: Consider maintaining a sorted contain if its frequent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::partial_sort` if you need them in order, otherwise `std::nth_element`, using `greater` as your predicate in either case.

I can't tell if by extract you mean you want to remove, but if you do then another option is heapifying your container with `make_heap` and then yanking the `N` elements out of it.

Comment: side question: is `partial_sort(it, it+K, it+N)` always cheaper than the combo `nth_element(it, it+K, it+N)` followed by `sort(it, it+K)` for large enough `K < N`?

Comment: @rhalbersma: the second variant should have asymptotic time complexity `O(K*log K + N)` which is asymptotically less than `O(N log K)` of the first. If it's (not) always cheaper, I can't say. Profile.

Answer (score 4):

To get the `n` smallest elements, use [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

```
std::vector<int> v = { 2, 6, 1, 13, 51, 5, 0, -1 };

std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end());

// now v[0], v[1], v[2] are the smallest, not otherwise sorted
```

Make sure to `#include <algorithm>`. An optional predicate may be supplied for customizing the sort order (e.g. `std::greater<int>`).